# Having my table with a minimum height and rows aligned top

Tags: css

I would like ta have a table with a minimum height (ex: 100px) so when there is no data in this table I still have a minimal height. I also would like to have rows in this table to be aligned on top so that when I have only 1 element in this table this element should not be aligned middle but top.

Here is my result in this jsFiddle so far: http://jsfiddle.net/ttrMe

**The problem is that my items are aligned middle.**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You mean like with #mytable tr { vertical-align: top; }?

Comment: I already try that but the problem is when I have 2 rows (+heading) in my table see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ttrMe/7/

Comment: Tip: The question could be more clear about what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers have provided `vertical-align: top` as the answer, which does answer the specific question. However, I think your approach to the border is flawed.

```
.tablewrapper {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    width: 70%;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
}
.mytable {
    width: 100%;
}
.mytable th {
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 20px;
}
.mytable td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ttrMe/16/

Note, I changed the border to be on the `#tablewrapper` div element which wraps the `.mytable`. Also note, I changed the `id`s to `class`es so I could have more than one and demonstrate the difference. Additionally, the `min-height` does not work alone with the `table` element, but does with the `div`.

**EDIT**

jsFiddle applies a CSS reset (*Normalize CSS* checkbox on the left), so you might not see the exact same look in your page unless you also reset. In that case, you'll probably want:

```
.mytable {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ttrMe/17/

Comment: Yep, after the previous attempts, I was wondering along this lines. Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the vertical alignment of the row text?

```
#mytable tr td {
    vertical-align: top;            
}
```

I added this to your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttrMe/4/), see if that's what you want.

Comment: At least in FF, not quite sure that does the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/ttrMe/8/ All of the text ends up on the top (overlapping).

Comment: The problem here is when there are more that one row (+heading) the second one is too much low. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/ttrMe/13/